# Renaming localhost

Tags: webserver, localhost

By default `127.0.0.1` has the *localhost* alias.

1. I found several approaches to changing it to a different string, but what is the standard, effective and safe best-practice way of doing it?
2. Can I give the same IP, but with a different port, a specific/different alias e.g. when I type *marius* to get  responses from the server listening to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`?

Comment: What software is running behind that port? Most software allows you to change the listening port.

Comment: I'm running *WEBrick*, the *rails* embedded web server. But I wanted to also be able to have *Apache* responding at `:8080`. Would changing the IP (e.g. `127.0.0.2`), and then give that one another alias be a better approach?

Comment: Don't remove the localhost alias. It's likely some applications rely on it. Instead, add more aliases like Josh Taylor shows.

Comment: In the apache config, you can configure virtual hosts (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/) to respond to different *domains/aliases*. I am sure you know this but there is no way through which you can run two processes listening on the same port.

Comment: @Khaja Good remark. And yes, the question was intended with at least 2 different ports (or 2 different IPs if not) to differentiate between the aliases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I know of is to edit your `/etc/hosts` file.

So for example you could have this:

`127.0.0.1  localhost marius`

I'm not totally sure on changing port though, as you shouldn't use ports in the hosts file.

Comment: why shouldn't you use ports in the hosts file?

Comment: The hostfile is used for resolving host names (DNS). For port forwarding, you'll need a solution like IPTables.