# create an alias for `localhost:8080/` as `www.my-domain.com/`

Tags: 12.04, webserver, localhost, hosts

In ubuntu, I want to create an alias for `localhost:8080/` as `www.my-domain.com/`. So that whenever I type `www.my-domain.com/` in URL field, it shows up from `localhost:8080/`. What is the easiest way to set this up ? Is there any application that could just do this mapping?

In windows, I used to use Fiddler2 to achieve the same goals.

Comment: Do you want this to be browser-independent?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26386/renaming-localhost

Comment: @saiarcot895: No its not! The OP has given an example for localhost, its not how to rename it.

Comment: @Jobin: Preferably yes, but browser dependent may also be acceptable.

Comment: @saiarcot895: I also had a look to that question earlier but the answer there doesn't work for port forwarding..

Answer (score 10):

You can add a `/etc/hosts` entry like the following:

```
127.0.0.2   my-domain.com
```

Make sure to use a `lo` address unused before.

Then you add an iptables rule to redirect the traffic incoming into `127.0.0.2:8080` to `127.0.0.1:80`.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

For doing this on firefox, you can install the [Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) add-on. After installing, restart firefox and then go to **Tools > Add-ons > Redirector > Preferences**.

Click on "New Redirect...". And in the "Include Pattern" field add `www.my-domain.com/` or whatever you want the redirection to occur **from**.
And in the "Redirect to" field, add `localhost:8000`. Type `www.my-domain.com/` in the "Example URL" field and click "Test pattern" if you want to confirm it works. If you see this:

[image: redirection successful]

You will be able to type `www.my-domain.com/` to go to localhost:8000.

Comment: anything similar for chrome as well ?

Comment: oops .. that is a redirect solution, not an alias.. sorry I didn't wanted this..

Comment: @user01: How exactly would it matter?

Comment: @user01: Did you have a look at the link posted by saiarcot895: askubuntu.com/questions/26386/renaming-localhost?

Comment: actually it does.. I use domain as alias for localhost while in developemnt mode